# anaconda install new envs meet false

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, environment-variables

I have created 5 envs in anaconda, which have never meet problems。But today I create a new env based Python 3.5 when the new envs installed py3.5 package, the loading progress bar is stopping 5 %, others packages go well. Because of py3.5 package, the env stalling is stopping. Then I restart conda envs, they all have failed, even I change the envs name different from the first one, it also doesn't work.

Here is the error information, please check the problem:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\何文轩> conda create --name paddle python=3.7 
>> WARNING: A space was detected in your requested environment path
'E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\paddle' 
Spaces in paths can sometimes be problematic. 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: done
```

Comment: Please post your error as text rather than an image.

Comment: (base) PS C:\Users\何文轩> conda create --name paddle python=3.7
>>
WARNING: A space was detected in your requested environment path
'E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\paddle'
Spaces in paths can sometimes be problematic.
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

Answer (score -1):

Spaces in path can sometimes be problematic - remove the spaces.

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

Comment: The OP's problem is with spaces in the folder name, not in their environment name. I have a work-provided laptop and before I got it my user name was set to my first and last name with a space in the middle. I cannot change my user name. So all my environments will have a space in their path until I reinstall Anaconda to a different folder.