# A space was detected in your requested environment path

Tags: python-3.x, path, spyder, whitespace, anaconda3

WARNING: A space was detected in your requested environment path
'C:\Users\ARAVIND KUMAR\anaconda3\envs\myenvname'
Spaces in paths can sometimes be problematic.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when i install thinter i got this error message on spyder console

Comment: @Aravind Kumar 
Duplicate of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955462/anaconda-install-new-envs-meet-false

(Buzzy Hopewell's reply)

This is not an error but simply a warning , just like what it clearly says on your terminal. From what I noticed, it is probably raised due to the spaces in the folder name - ARAVIND KUMAR.